# Working code example of PHP XML-RPC connex to site?

Tags: xml-rpc

I'm working on an integration between an outside app (which needs to pull user names and some taxonomy data, and create new posts) and a WordPress site. I'm running the latest build of WP (4.0).

The XML-RPC documentation being as spare as it is, I'm hoping someone out there can just pastebin a recent (2014?) working example. Honestly, the google machine simply fails on this one.

Ideally, the code example would use the WP's bundled libraries (class-IXR.php, class-wp-http-ixr-client.php) rather than some outside XMLRPC library.

Here's what's NOT working (yet):

```
<?php
get_header(); 

include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php' );
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-http-ixr-client.php' );

$client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_CLIENT( 'redactedSITEURL' );


$post = array(
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'post_status' => 'draft',
     'post_title' => 'Test Post',
     'post_content' => 'This is my test post',
     'post_author' => 1
);

$data = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.newPost', array('redactedURL.com', 'redactedUNAME', 'redactedPASSWORD', $post);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'redactedSITEURL.com/xmlrpc.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$exec = curl_exec($ch);
$response = xmlrpc_decode($exec);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was being stupid, so I stopped that.

I'd assumed that a) any answer older than two years would be out-of-date; b) I'd need a special WP flavor of the base IXR library; I was confused, and took the sparseness of the wp.org documentation as "they're not telling the whole story" instead of "the tool is very basic at the use interface."

This code works, in conjunction with the IXR library found at [incutio.com](http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/):

```
include('IXR_Library.php');

$usr = 'theusername';
$pwd = 'thepassword';
$xmlrpc = 'http://not-therealurl.com/xmlrpc.php';
$client = new IXR_Client($xmlrpc);

$client -> debug = true; //optional but useful

$params = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_title' => 'Test Post',
    'post_author' => 4,
    'post_excerpt' => 'This is my test excerpt',
    'post_content' => 'This is my test post. Now its longer than the excerpt.'
);

$res = $client -> query('wp.newPost',1, $usr, $pwd, $params);
```

Answer (score 2):

How complex do you want the example to be?

This outputs "Hello".

```
$client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_Client('http://example.com/xmlrpc.php');
$client->query('demo.sayHello');
echo $client->getResponse();
```

This outputs "9".

```
$client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_Client('http://example.com/xmlrpc.php');
$client->query('demo.addTwoNumbers', 4, 5);
echo $client->getResponse();
```

This gets the WordPress version:

```
$client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_Client('http://example.com/xmlrpc.php');
$client->query('wp.getOptions', 0, 'username', 'password', 'software_version');
$response = $client->getResponse();
echo $response['software_version']['value'];
```

Source: Me, 4 years ago:
http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-and-xml-rpc/

Comment: Otto, your example seems to be targeted at a WordPress install pulling from / pushing to another WP install. I'm trying to work up a PHP script which will allow an outside app to interact with a site. I'm sure it's similar, but can you point the way a little for me?